# Vagrant fail to run triggers: Unknown configuration section 'trigger'

Tags: vagrant

Trying to execute a very basic example of triggers usage shown in the official [docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/triggers/usage.html):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.trigger.before :up do |trigger|
    trigger.name = "Hello world"
    trigger.info = "I am running before vagrant up!!"
  end

  config.trigger.after :up do |trigger|
    trigger.name = "Hello world"
    trigger.info = "I am running after vagrant up!!"
  end

  config.vm.define "ubuntu" do |ubuntu|
    ubuntu.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  end

end
```

Failing with the following error:

> Vagrant: Unknown configuration section 'trigger'.

Any idea?

---

(*) The [vagrant-triggers](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers) plugin was [merged](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/pull/9713) to  [Vagrant 2.1.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/v2.2.5/CHANGELOG.md#210-may-3-2018) in may 2018.

Comment: If you have the vagrant-triggers plugin installed, you usually need to remove it if you are using the native functionality.

Comment: No - I don't have it installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, For some reason I thought I was on latest Version of Vagrant on local machine.

**Problem was fixed after upgrading** from version 2.0.2 to latest (currently 2.2.5).

Output looks fine now:

```
==> ubuntu: Running action triggers before up ...
==> ubuntu: Running trigger: Hello world...
==> ubuntu: I am running before vagrant up!!

....

==> ubuntu: Running action triggers after up ...
==> ubuntu: Running trigger: Hello world...
==> ubuntu: I am running after vagrant up!!
```

I hope it will help anybody...